# Link to "What's a positive question record" canonical post when people have a negative question record

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, badge-progress

Every now and then people will ask what a positive question record is and how it is calculated, generating unnecessary duplicates and *perhaps* wasting time & energy.

This *could* somewhat be alleviated if the user interface could also play its part towards educating users.

**Why not link to some educational material right at the point where people will invariably raise an eyebrow?**

[image]

Seems like a quick win to me.

Comment: Do you actually have a "what's a positive question record?" canonical reference you're thinking of, or will one need to be created?

Comment: @nitsua60 Good point. I'm pretty sure one must exist already so I'll search around and update this question with some candidates.